# How c varibles are stored?

Tags: c

**In c program,how varibles address are generated?It means all varibles are stored in the    starting of the word address?**

Comment: With all due respect I think you need to head to the library and get a book on C-programming, your question is not clear.

Comment: I understand not everyone on this site is a native English speaker, but I honestly have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

That is completely up to the implementation. It is not guaranteed that a variable will end up in memory at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is all implementation dependant.

Compilers often have some means to control and/or enquire about alignment of types. For intance, in gcc you can do the following:

```
int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;
```

which aligns x on a 16 byte boundary.

In gcc you can also use `__alignof__ (int)` to get the alignment of int variables.